# How to specify node version for Maven in CDK Builds

Tags: aws-cdk

When I try to run unit tests on my CDK Java project with `mvn test`, I get an error that `Node v8.9.1 has reached end-of-life and is not supported.`.

But Node v12.22.1 is my current version, which I check right before running Maven.

```
node --version
v12.22.1
mvn test
....
```

Curiously, if I run Maven through the IntelliJ GUI, it works.

I have set my node version with `nvm`, if that matters. And I'm on a Mac.

Is there some environment variable I need to set? How does the CDK determine which node to use?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Full output:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

!!                                                                                  !!

!!  Node v8.9.1 has reached end-of-life and is not supported.                       !!

!!  You may to encounter runtime issues, and should switch to a supported release.  !!

!!                                                                                  !!

!!  As of the current release, supported versions of node are:                      !!

!!  - ^12.7.0                                                                       !!

!!  - ^14.5.0                                                                       !!

!!  - ^16.3.0                                                                       !!

!!                                                                                  !!

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

(node:14462) Warning: process.on(SIGPROF) is reserved while debugging

/private/var/folders/nr/dkx1p38s24nb7fx_qgcxggcm0000gn/T/jsii-java-runtime8055040669944096944/lib/program.js:467
            } catch {
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: My /usr/local/bin/node is version 8.9.1. It must be using that one. The Surefire plugin probably forks a new JVM and it must not be honoring the nvm setting. One thing I forgot to say is that `cdk deploy` and `cdk synth` work locally; the failure is only in running the tests. So that reinforces the theory that it's way the new JVM is launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Surefire plugin is using my /usr/local/bin/node, which was not installed with nvm. It was 8.9.1. I upgraded that node version and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Two things could be causing this.

1. In your build spec, you haven't specified the [runtime env](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/runtime-versions.html) as node. Even if you manually install node yourself, and the `--version` command returns it, when the commands run on your code build it will use the default. You have to define it in your codebuild buildspec.yaml with:

```
    phases:
      install:
         runtime-versions:
           nodejs: 12
```

If you don't specify this runtime-version, then any commands run - such as mvn - that are not direct node commands will automatically use 8.9.1

2. **assuming you have already provided this in your buildspec**, then the other potential problem is your Codebuild Image. If you are not set to Standard2.0 or greater, then you *cannot make use of runtimes*- they will always default to the base runtimes of node 8. (see [this reference for docker images on codebuild available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html) ) --  Unless you really need to otherwise, you should be using Ubuntu Standard 5.0. It has the most recent backend code that utilizes the Buildspec and gives you the most control.

It is worth noting, if you are using CDK, and you don't specify a [specific image to use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.html) it automatically defaults to Standard1.0 and the runtime-versions will be ignored. More annoyingly, if you are in Standard1.0 it will print a warning that runtime-versions is ignored but not stop the process... and since codebuilds ignore the --quiet flags of most commands, it can very easily get lost in the spam.

Comment: I'm not using CodeBuild, this is just on my local laptop. Our builds on Circle CI work fine, it's just my machine so far that has the issue. I've never used CodeBuild and I'm newish to CDK, so I don't think your comments apply to my case, but I could easily be wrong, and please let me know if so. Thanks!

Comment: This seems more like a symlink issue than a CDK one.  I believe you recognize that as you mentioned you have set the version for maven to use, but CDK does not seem to be respecting that - See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/cdk/latest/guide/work-with-cdk-java.html for some information on setting up your dependency file  - likely something is incorrect for your local as opposed to your teammates.